# How do I convert List<String?> to List<String> in .NET 6 / C# 10?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Using .NET 6 I have the following:

```
List<String> values = new List<String?> { null, "", "value" }
  .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
  .Select(y => y)
  .ToList();
```

But I am getting the warning:

> Nullability of reference types in value of type 'string?[]' doesn't match target type 'string[]'.

I thought that using

```
.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
```

would solve the problem but it doesn't. How to fix this?

Comment: `.Cast<string>()` would force it - but there are probably better ways

Comment: `.Select(y => y!)` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one case where you know better, and can assure the compiler the value is not `null` via `.Select(y => y!)`

```
List<string> values = new List<string?> { null, "", "value" }
   .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
   .Select(y => y!)
   .ToList();
```

<sub>**Note** : `.Select(y => y.Value)` is not going to work, as strings are *reference types* and `string?` represents a *nullable reference type*, not a *nullable value type*</sub>

As mentioned in the comments by [@Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner). You could also use `.Cast<string>()` to similar effect, which is essentially just an iterator and regular cast in a generic method, in turn assuring you have the desired result.

```
List<string> values = new List<string?> { null, "", "value" }
   .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
   .Cast<string>()
   .ToList();
```

And yet another way (albeit it a little harder to reason about) though likely more efficient

```
List<string> values = new List<string?> { null, "", "value" }
   .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))!
   .ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

To filter out nulls from enumerable of nullable reference types and "convert" it to non-nullable you can use the [null-forgiving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) operator after `ToList` without extra `Select`:

```cs
List<string> values = new List<string?> { null, "", "value" }
  .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
  .ToList()!;
```

[sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWDkQHQBkBLAOwEdM4BmZMRAYUQG9ZFXEBiYgVwBseBDAEY8ApohHEholmxDUQqRAFkAFAEpEM1sxhs9iIgGcALgB4U8AHyIAbvx5cRhxAF5ExEQHcDhE+YjwAPzWjO68PAA0iABE0VHRdg4i0YgAvlr6ergA6gAWIgBOIioAHq7WAIQWuACShgBy4QDyBQCiALYADsYAnqVqahmZrLgAKgD2RsbqFRR66TCpQA)

Also among other options you can use query syntax:

```cs
List<string> values = (from s in new List<string?> { null, "", "value" }
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
    select s)
    .ToList();
```

[@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgAwFgBQiCM65IARyYB0AMgJZQCOA3DvoQCy1oDEUEANhwIYBGHAUzwCofQenTkAzsAA8hJAD48AN24cIAqXgC8eABQAzMAHsAtnm0U8eKAIDueaXIUB+ZQG9bnDgBo8AEQB/gFqGgIBeAC+6DY29gAWAmBCAIQKRACSUgByPgDyYACiZgAOwACe+lIAlLFxUgKCAMbAlnVocXhEAComzvo11EA===)

Note that if the goal is to only filter `null`'s `OfType` can be used instead of `Where`-`Select`:

```cs
List<string> values = new List<string?> { null, "", "value" }
  .OfType<string>()
  .ToList();
```

[@sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMA6AGQEsoBHAbj0JMwBZHcnMBOACgCJAPBuAQff4BKDlwIB+ANoBdIgEMiAXiIBvIlAgAbXTCL8AZgHtT/Qzv2H+AIyVh+RAL4dSAZgA8pAgD4WAgBnNWU8IgiiMgB5YwAVAE8ABwBTH0x/Xgk8MzAUpQBjAAteIgA3RyIqKqhAkLFwyNI+KmzcIA===)

Comment: I highly doubt sharplab got it correct there.

Comment: @TanveerBadar what do you mean? The null-forgiving operator removes the warning. Verified in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M49gjk) and using Rider and `dotnet build`.

Comment: nvm, I thought one would read something akin to `ToList<string!>()` but it turns out your solution addresses everything and the final `!` is not a shallow application of the warning suppression but suppresses every warning.